# The 'order_by' method not working on a foreign key query

Tags: python, django

I can't figure out how to get this 'order_by' to work.

```
reviews = product.review_set.all().order_by('-created_at')
```

Comment: What is the exception you are getting ?

Comment: The way I'm using it, I can't see the exception. But do you know if it is possible to do an 'order_by' on an 'object_set.all()'?

Comment: It should work, not enough information about your models and the result you getting

Comment: To provide more hints, you might want to consider showing your DB table schema. Have you tried to isolate this call to rule out interfering controller actions? Stuff like that. The line on its own isn't helpful enough.

Comment: Sorry for the poor question, I just wanted to know if this is a legitimate line of code. I couldn't find anything in the docs on doing an 'order_by' on an 'object_set', but if Basalex says it should work I appreciate the response that's all I wanted.

Comment: I believe what I was looking for which I think is the correct way to write my original line is `reviews = product.review_set.order_by('-created_at').all()`

Answer (score 0):

If this makes it easier to understand, the query you posted:

```
reviews = product.review_set.all()
```

is equivalent to:

```
reviews = Review.objects.filter(product=product)
```

I.e. both of those return the same queryset on which you can apply the `order_by` statement.

Comment: thanks, I believe what I was looking for which I think is the correct way to write my original line is `reviews = product.review_set.order_by('-created_at').all()`

Comment: That's perfectly fine, additionally, the last `all()` is redundant - the above is equivalent to `product.review_set.order_by('-created_at')`